# python open(file) only read about 2507000 lines?

Tags: python, io

I tried to read a big file use python but it seems that python only process about 2507000 lines and then stop. Could you suggest why?

I am using Python 2.7 32bit on windows. I also post the code I am using. Thanks.

```
counter = 0
with open(input) as file:
    for line in file:
        counter += 1
        if counter % 1000 == 0:
            sys.stderr.write(str(counter) + "lines processed.\n")
```

Comment: 1) I wouldn't use the name `file` for a variable name (it's a builtin type).  2) `for counter,line in enumerate(fileobj,1)` would be a slighty more elegant way to do what you're doing here. 3) Maybe your file has less than 2508000 lines ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "stop"?  Does the program crash?  Is there an error message?  Does it freeze?  If so, is it consuming CPU?

Comment: Can you post the file or is that confidential? I would like to test. My immediate suggestion is to try an infinite while loop (that is, `while True:` iterate through the lines and count them.) But also I am curious why you can't do `len(file)` if each line is an item in it.

Comment: @rofls -- files don't have a `__len__` method, so `len(file)` won't work.  I suppose you could try `len(file.readlines())`, but that's not a real solution.

Comment: What does your output look like? At some point your `counter` variable will overflow and you will start seeing some funny output.

Comment: @mbatchkarov: Python integers are arbitrary-precision; they won't overflow.

Comment: hi all, thanks for quick reply. The file have 4006794 lines in it, use "wc -l". It seems that the script exit normal.

Comment: @gstar2002: are you 100% certain? Is there a mix of `\r` and `\n` characters in the file perhaps?

Comment: wc is for word count and not for line count. right? try opening the file in vi to see the line count.

Comment: @shahkalpesh - `-l` option is for lines.

Comment: My only guess would be that there is something wrong/od in the file around that linenr.. I have NO problem reading files containing 1000.000.000 lines.... I am working alot with big wordlists.. Also using Python 2.7

Comment: Try universal newlines mode: `open(input, "U")`

Comment: @Fenikso: Thank you for your answer.OP: Where was this file created? Linux? windows? Could this be due to crlf mismatch?

Comment: @JanneKarila, your tip works!! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different programs may count lines differently, depending on how they expect lines to be delimited. The DOS/Windows convention is `\r\n` and the Unix convention is `\n` as the delimiter.

If you open the file in universal newlines mode using `open(filename, "U")`, your program will recognize all the different delimiters.